No internet on Ubuntu 24.04
I have installed a virtual box on the Ubuntu 24.04 dedicated server and installed Windows 11 in a virtual environment. Then installed a Public fixed IP from a fast host so I could access the VM anyway but when I changed the connection to bridge I lost all Internet connection and got this message Connection failed Activation of network connection
When I am on LAN with DHCP internet, everything is ok.
